# Terraform aws_spot_fleet_request iam_instance_profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I read the Terraform spot fleet example usages from [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html).

What is the significance of "iam_instance_profile_arn" and what does it do in Example 1?

I'm getting the error "launch_specification.0: invalid or unknown key: tags" in some cases, while not in others so I thought maybe it is related to the iam_profile.

```
iam_instance_profile_arn  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.example.arn}"
```

Example 1:

```
# Request a Spot fleet
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "cheap_compute" {
  iam_fleet_role      = "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/spot-fleet"
  spot_price          = "0.03"
  allocation_strategy = "diversified"
  target_capacity     = 6
  valid_until         = "2019-11-04T20:44:20Z"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type             = "m4.10xlarge"
    ami                       = "ami-1234"
    spot_price                = "2.793"
    placement_tenancy         = "dedicated"
    iam_instance_profile_arn  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.example.arn}"
  }

  launch_specification {
    instance_type             = "m4.4xlarge"
    ami                       = "ami-5678"
    key_name                  = "my-key"
    spot_price                = "1.117"
    iam_instance_profile_arn  = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.example.arn}"
    availability_zone         = "us-west-1a"
    subnet_id                 = "subnet-1234"
    weighted_capacity         = 35

    root_block_device {
      volume_size = "300"
      volume_type = "gp2"
    }

    tags {
      Name = "spot-fleet-example"
    }
  }
}
```

Example 2:

```
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "foo" {
  iam_fleet_role  = "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/spot-fleet"
  spot_price      = "0.005"
  target_capacity = 2
  valid_until     = "2019-11-04T20:44:20Z"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type     = "m1.small"
    ami               = "ami-d06a90b0"
    key_name          = "my-key"
    availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  }

  launch_specification {
    instance_type     = "m3.large"
    ami               = "ami-d06a90b0"
    key_name          = "my-key"
    availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_iam_policy_attachment.test-attach"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The instance profile is unrelated to the error. The error is saying this:

```
tags {
       Name = "spot-fleet-example"
     }
```

Part of the first example isnt recognized. You can read about what instance profiles are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html):

> An instance profile is a container for an IAM role that you can use to
>   pass role information to an EC2 instance when the instance starts.